# R - Remove everything after the second space in a data frame column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column in a data frame where each record is a list of names.

e.g. John Smith, Jane Smith, Joe Smith, Judy Smith, etc...

I want to delete everything except the first name for the entire column, basically from the first comma onwards, so my column will just have one name.

e.g. John Smith

I've tried playing around with sub, gsub, regex, but I am lost. I just started using R about two days ago and was doing fine until I hit this roadblock.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: So you want the rest of the entries in the column to be NA? Example:
Name, Age
John Smith, 25
NA, 30
NA, 40 ...

Comment: I think Brian means that each record (row) contains multiple names and he wants to retain the first, per row.

Comment: Oh okay. That makes much more sense :)

Comment: Since you start with R I will ask additional question: Do you really want this data frame to have one column with each entry being a string with comma separated names? Or maybe you were reading the data.frame from the file and it is supposed to be one name per column? I'm asking just in case...

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(df$name, ","), function(x) x[[1]])` or more conveniently `sapply(strsplit(df$name, ","), `[[`, 1)`

Comment: The name column is just one of many columns in the data frame.

I want to delete everything from the entries except for the first name, eg: John Smith

I want to do that for every row. There are about a thousand rows, each with a list of names in this column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your names are in a column called `Name` in data frame `mydata`, try this first. It says "replace a comma followed by anything to the end of the line with an empty string".

```
sub(",.+", "", mydata$Name)
```

If it looks like that worked, assign the result to the column:

```
mydata$Name <- sub(",.+", "", mydata$Name)
```

Comment: This accomplished exactly what I needed. Thanks a mil!

Answer (score 0):

If your data frame is like this:

```
df = data.frame(names = c("John Smith, Jane Smith, Joe Smith, Judy Smith","Jane Smith, Joe Smith, Judy Smith","Joe Smith, Judy Smith","Judy Smith"))

> df
                                          names
1 John Smith, Jane Smith, Joe Smith, Judy Smith
2             Jane Smith, Joe Smith, Judy Smith
3                         Joe Smith, Judy Smith
4                                    Judy Smith
```

Then do:

```
df$first = sub(",.*","",df$names)
```

Result:

```
> df
                                          names      first
1 John Smith, Jane Smith, Joe Smith, Judy Smith John Smith
2             Jane Smith, Joe Smith, Judy Smith Jane Smith
3                         Joe Smith, Judy Smith  Joe Smith
4                                    Judy Smith Judy Smith
```

Answer (score 0):

stringr answer although it is the same

```
pattern <- data.frame("colid" = c(1, 2), 
                      "text" = c("john smith, jane smith", "jon stewart, steven colbert"))
pattern %>% 
  mutate(text2 = str_replace_all(text, ",.*", ""))
```